# AWS Lambda: it is possible to use Oracle Java SDK?

Tags: java, oracle, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to use Amazon Lambda to run a component. However, this component has dependencies with some packages which seem to be only available in the Oracle's SDK.

I have read that AWS Lambda functions run on Linux Amazon AMI (which are Open SDK based). Actually, some time ago I tried to run my project on an EC2 instance and faced the same problem, so I switched to a standard Ubuntu 14.04 and I installed the Oracle Java 8 SDK.

Do you have any ideas?

Edit: the problem I'm finding is:

```
[2016-11-21T23:58:02.100] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/webkit/network/CookieManager
[2016-11-21T23:58:02.100] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/webkit/network/CookieManager
[2016-11-21T23:58:02.100] at com.machinepublishers.jbrowserdriver.JBrowserDriverServer.main(JBrowserDriverServer.java:74)
```

I think that class is only available in the Oracle's Java SDK.

Comment: No...Please check:  **Pre-requisites**

There's no need to install any web browser and this works fine on a server (headless). Java 8 (Oracle JDK/JRE or OpenJDK) is required.

Linux users: on Debian/Ubuntu install the following, apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk openjfx. Resource Link: https://libraries.io/maven/com.machinepublishers:jbrowserdriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check [Lambda Execution Environment and Available Libraries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html), then you will get

> If you are using any native binaries in your code, make sure they are
>   compiled in this environment. Note that **only 64-bit binaries are
>   supported on AWS Lambda.**
>
> AWS Lambda supports the following runtime versions:
>
> 1. Node.js – v0.10.36, v4.3.2 (recommended)
> 2. Java – Java 8
> 3. Python – Python 2.7

Q: What is the JVM environment Lambda uses for execution of my function?

> Ans: Lambda provides the Amazon Linux build of openjdk 1.8.

Q: How do I compile my AWS Lambda function Java code?

> You can use standard tools like Maven or Gradle to compile your Lambda
>   function. Your build process should mimic the same build process you
>   would use to compile any Java code that depends on the AWS SDK. R**un
>   your Java compiler tool on your source files and include the AWS SDK
>   1.9 or later with transitive dependencies on your classpath.** For more details, see [aws documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-lambda.html).

You can also check: [AWS Lambda: How It Works](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html)

### UPDATE:

If you check the [github for jbrowserdriver](https://github.com/machinepublishers/jbrowserdriver), the pre-requisite are given

### Prerequisites

**Java 8 with JavaFX:**

- Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS, Debian 8 Jessie (Backports), Debian 9
  Stretch:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjfx
  ```
- Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 LTS:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer libgtk2.0 libxtst6 libxslt1.1 fonts-freefont-ttf libasound2 && sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```
- Mac, Windows, Linux:

  [install Oracle Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) (**note: choose either the JRE or JDK but not the "Server JRE" since it doesn't include JavaFX**)

### Resource Link:

1. https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#functions-java

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems that CookieManager is a part of openjfx (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/com/sun/webkit/network/CookieManager.java). Then, the problem is not about opensdk/oracle issues but about the absence of a package in the Lambda environment, right? Then the response could be summarized like: "Oracle SDK is not supported in AWS Lambda, but regarding your particular issue, the problem apparently is caused because `openjfx` is not present".